# Android browser badge icons not displaying correctly

Tags: bug, profile-page

I've just looked on the StackOverflow website on my HTC One m9 and noticed some issues with the user activity and profile pages. This does seem to affect other network websites including Meta SE.

It only seems to effect the larger icons and not the smallest ones.

This is using Chrome on Android 5.0.2

[image]
[image]
[image]

Would guess it's a quick fix.